# Why doesn't my Angular test like my custom form validation function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an angular component - "FooComponent" - that I'm trying to test using Karma/Jasmine.

Here is some relevant code in the foo.component.spec.ts file:

```
describe('FooComponent', () => {
    let component: FooComponent
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooComponent>
    let componentElement: DebugElement
    let bar: FormControl

...

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooComponent)
    component = fixture.componentInstance
    fixture.detectChanges()
    component.ngOnInit()
    componentElement = fixture.debugElement
    bar = component.bar
  })

it('should create the FooComponent', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy()
})
```

I'm getting the following error when running `ng test` :

```
Chrome 63.0.3239 (Windows 10 0.0.0) FooComponent should create the 
FooComponent FAILED

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'validate' of undefined
        at normalizeValidator .../node_modules/@angular/forms/esm5/forms.js:1059:23)
        at Array.map (<anonymous>)
        at composeValidators .../node_modules/@angular/forms/esm5/forms.js:2422:1)
        at coerceToValidator .../node_modules/@angular/forms/esm5/forms.js:2826:1)
        at new FormControl .../node_modules/@angular/forms/esm5/forms.js:3881:1)
        at FooComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/foo/foo.component.ts.FooComponent.createFormControls ....../src/app/foo/foo.component.ts:43:16)
        at FooComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/foo/foo.component.ts.FooComponent.ngOnInit ....../src/app/foo/foo.component.ts:37:10)
        at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline .../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:12400:1)
        at checkAndUpdateNodeInline .../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13927:1)
        at checkAndUpdateNode .../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13870:1)
```

As you can see, lines 37 and 43 of foo.component.ts are offensive:

```
ngOnInit() {
    //the following is line 37
    this.createFormControls()
    this.createForm()
}

createFormControls() {
    //the following is line 43
    this.bar = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.fooService.validateBar])
}

createForm() {
    this.fooForm = new FormGroup({
        bar: this.bar
    })
}
```

So it looks like it does not like something about the custom validation function I wrote in FooService (which I am injecting into FooComponent). Here is that function within foo.service.ts:

```
validateBar(bar: FormControl) {
    return bar.value.length == 10 ? null: { invalidBar: true }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I see you have this in your `beforeEach`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    ...
    component.ngOnInit()
    ...
});
```

You should not invoke `ngOnInit()` directly, that method is invoked by the test runner when you do this:

```
fixture.detectChanges()
```

You can refer to the docs where this is explained: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles on this, "cannot read property 'validate' of undefined" errors are perhaps the most annoying things to uncover and there are few answers describing what to try.

The problem is that your formGroup is undefined, yet your HTML is trying to render and check for formGroup.valid (like if your forms submit button is enabled)

Usually mocking the FormBuilder(), the FormGroup, building up a data object the resuable component needs, then providing it to the component is enough and everything is dandy. But there are some times that it's not

Anyways.. Try adding an ngIf so the controls are initialized before your component is allowed to render

```
<form class="form-popup" *ngIf="formGroup && formGroup.controls.length" [formGroup]="formGroup">
```

This is generally only a problem when a component uses a reusable component (for looks), then injects the formGroup data on ngOnInit. Wa-lah - the

```
<ng-template *ngComponentOutlet="component;injector:injector"></ng-template
```

Didn't quite have the data yet and fixture.detectChanges() wasn't quite enough for it to render.

Comment: "Voila!" not "Wa-lah".